# not able to Install codeception in windows

Tags: codeception

> C:\wamp\www\project\automation\codeception>
>
> php codecept.phar bootstrap
>       PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar://C:/wamp/www/project/aut
>       omation/codeception/codecept.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php
>   on
>       line 24
>       PHP Stack trace:
>       PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\project\automation\codeception\codecept.phar:0
>       PHP   2. require_once() C:\wamp\www\project\automation\codeception\codecept.phar
>       :5
>       PHP   3. require_once() phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/codeception/codece
>       pt.phar/autoload.php:4
>       PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit47cdf60ec5efa3860ea7539ac6be7d49::getLoader()
>   pha
>       r://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/codeception/codecept.phar/vendor/autoload.php
>       :7
>       PHP   5. composerRequire47cdf60ec5efa3860ea7539ac6be7d49() phar://C:/wamp/www/pr
>       oject/automation/codeception/codecept.phar/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:52
>
> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automati
> on/codeception/codecept.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php
> ```
>
> on line
>       24
>
> ```
> Call Stack:
>     0.0110     658208   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\project\automation\codeception\c
> odecept.phar:0
>     0.0128     671848   2. require_once('phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/c
> odeception/codecept.phar/autoload.php') C:\wamp\www\project\automation\codecepti
> on\codecept.phar:5
>     0.0133     673968   3. require_once('phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/c
> odeception/codecept.phar/vendor/autoload.php') phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automa
> tion/codeception/codecept.phar/autoload.php:4
>     0.0137     695984   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit47cdf60ec5efa3860ea7539ac6be7d4
> 9::getLoader() phar://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/codeception/codecept.phar/v
> endor/autoload.php:7
>     0.0204    1014824   5. composerRequire47cdf60ec5efa3860ea7539ac6be7d49() pha
> r://C:/wamp/www/project/automation/codeception/codecept.phar/vendor/composer/aut
> oload_real.php:52
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of Windows. Probably you are running PHP 5.3 or less. In this case you should use Codeception 1.8.x, as pointed out here: http://codeception.com/builds

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.3 use the latest version of Codeception 1.8.x

1. Create a folder "TEST" in D:\

02.Download all codeception files into that folder
 # http://getcomposer.org/
 # http://codeception.com

03.Open command prompt and go to D:\TEST

04.Run php codecept.phar (D:\TEST> php codecept.phar)

05.Run php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception:*"

06.Go to D:\TEST\vendor\bin in command prompt

07.Run codecept bootstrap